# Should I send my son's birth certificate when applying for his B1-B2 visa?

Tags: usa, paperwork, b1-b2-visas

My 6 year old son will be traveling to the US with my wife. I applied online, paid the fee and got the confirmation email. In that email, in the section about the required documents for all visas, it says:

> Accompanying family members, unless entering the United States for another purpose, should present a marriage certificate (spouse) and/or birth certificate (for unmarried children under 21), as applicable.

What exactly does this mean? Should I also send his birth certificate by courier (he is eligible for courier application)?

Comment: That statement is definitely odd. Can you give some more context for it?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I don't know what else I can tell. This is the full text: https://www.immigration4us.com/required-documents-us-visas.

Comment: That is not an official US government website. It looks like some sort of visa agent. Be cautious about such services. Some are legitimate but others can be scams.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But the email that I received contains the exact same text. I just linked it here because it was more convenient than pasting the while content.